# nHibernate QueryOver Projects - are Select and Where the same thing?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-projections

Using nHibernate QueryOver, if I want to enforce a projection for performance, are "Select" and "Where" the same thing? In other words, will ..

```
        var member = session.QueryOver<Member>()
            .Select( projections => projections.Email == model.Email )
            .Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

Run the same as

```
        var member = session.QueryOver<Member>()
            .Where( context => context.Email == model.Email )
            .Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
```

Or is there a difference in the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` projects (you could also say *maps*); `Where` filters. This is the same as SQL and all LINQ providers (and QueryOver is also sort of a LINQ provider). It seems that in this case you want to filter, not project, so you need `Where`

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was going for. I actually got the same result with both queries, but I presumed something else was happening underneath the hood that I might not understand.

Answer (score 1):

No offense intended, but I think the best way to answer a question like the one you asked is to try it. Sometimes things become clearer when you can see the output.

That said, when you use `Select`, you're telling NHibernate how to project your data. This determines the final makeup of the data resulting from the query. There's a little bit more to this, but that's the general idea. You use `Where` when you want to specify the criteria that the data that you are querying should satisfy.

Comment: I did try it, and while I received the same data result, that doesn't mean they are the same thing. There are thousands of things going on under the hood in an ORM that a developer of my limited experience doesn't yet grasp.

Comment: I wasn't clear. Take a look at the SQL that is generated by the query and you'll see what I'm talking about. I don't know which database system you're using, but if you're using SQL server, you can fire up SQL profiler and see the SQL that is sent to the database. There's also NHibernate Profiler, which is a fantastic tool that shows you precisely what is going on under the covers.